# Percentage sign binary operator in ggplot R

Tags: r, binary, operator-keyword, percentage, sign

I used percentage signs in the column names of a data frame. So far, I haven't encountered any disadvantages by doing so.

Now I would like to create a ggplot with my data and get the following error due to the use of percentage signs:

```
Error in stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") + geom_boxplot() : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Is there any way to still create a ggplot without having to remove the percentage sign in the column name?
I tried putting the name in apostrophes, but this didn't help:

```
#'Values_in%'
#`Values_in%`
```

Here is a test data frame:

```
test_data_frame <- as.data.frame(rnorm(n=10, mean=5, sd=1))
test_data_frame[,2] <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
colnames(test_data_frame) <- c("Values", "Labels_assign") ## like this it works in ggplot
colnames(test_data_frame) <- c("Values_in%", "Labels_assign") ## this doesn't work in ggplot
```

And here is the code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test_data_frame, aes(x=factor(Labels_assign), y=Values_in%, fill=factor(Labels_assign)))  + 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle("Box-Whisker-Plot") +
  xlab("X-Axis") +
  ylab("Y-Axis") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=16, hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(face="bold")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel2", name="Cluster")
```

Comment: Using `\`Values_in%\`` in the `aes()` call works for me.

Comment: Your are right, thanks! I don't know what went wrong during my first trials, but now as I try it again, it works!